# Compiling with MAKE after CMAKE doesn't work (MySQL on OS X)

Tags: macos, makefile, cmake

I'm trying to compile MySQL (5.5.29 in my case) on Mac OS X (10.8) but can't. I'm trying to follow [the instructions at MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/source-installation.html) but they seem to be written for Linux & Win only, this is what happens:

```
cmake . -G Xcode
-- Running cmake version 2.8.11.1
-- MySQL 5.5.29
-- [A lot of looking up and checking]
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/name/mysql-5.5.29

make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Using CMake 2.8.11 and GNU Make 3.81. I'm not sure I'm doing this right, any ideas are very welcome.

Comment: You could likely save yourself a lot of trouble by installing MySQL with one of the third-party package managers for OS X, like Homebrew or MacPorts.  MacPorts even has separate ports for 5.1, 5.5 (currently 5.5.30) and 5.6.  (http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=mysql)

Comment: Thanks, that's very true, but I'm in one of these wonderful situations, where I require a set of files (mysql header files) from this specific build, because they don't come with MAMP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to compile with make, why are you using the Xcode generator?  If you use the Xcode generator then no makefiles will be written: you'll need to use Xcode to compile.

Try using the makefile generator if you want to use make to compile.

Comment: Thank you, I actually had to specify `cmake . -G "Unix Makefile"`